# How to sum the data using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sum

I am trying to find straightforward methods to sum the data by various factors in ggplot.

Sample data (dat):

```
A B C 
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3

library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
dat1 <- gather(dat) #convert into long form with 'key' and 'value'
```

I have tried the following methods:

1. qplot(x, y, data=dat1[, sum(y)],by = "key,value", size=V1)
   Error in `[.data.frame`(dat1, , sum(y)) : object 'y' not found
2. ggplot(data = dat1, aes(x = key, y = value)) +
     stat_summary(fun.y = sum,  colour = "red", size  = 1)
   Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'key' not found

Can anyone recommend where I may be going wrong and alternatives to the same?

Comment: where is `dat2` created?

Comment: Please build a more reproducible example. Include the `tidyr` library. Create the `dat` dataframe: `dat <- data.frame(A = rep(1, 3), B = rep(2, 3), C = rep(3, 3))`. You are referencing `dat2` in your ggplot calls. What is `dat2`?

Comment: My bad. I have changed it

Comment: The `dat[, sum(y)]` will not work because there is no 'y' column and it is not a data.table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify the `geom`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dat1, aes(x = key, y = value))  +  
       stat_summary(fun.y = sum, geom="point", colour = "red", size = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: `fun.y` is deprecated. Now it's just `fun`.